# Android NDK: Where are the Sample Apps

Tags: android-ndk, sample

I'm just getting started tinkering with building executable files for Android using NDK (because I want to). I've eventually got my development environment set up on a Windows PC which includes the latest versions of Android Studio (2.1.2) and NDK (r12b). . . and Eclipse (which I intend to use because there's much more guidance on the web for Eclipse than the more recent Studio).

So, in order to verify my new development environment installation is OK, I'm about to build some of the minimal 'hello world' type test applications bundled with NDK.

According to https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/index.html "These samples are also contained in the NDK installation package; if you have already downloaded the NDK, you have them. They reside in $NDK/samples/, where $NDK is the NDK installation root."

No they don't. Nor are they in my SDK folder. Or anywhere else on my hard drive.

So my questions are, 'HelloJNI' and all the other samples refered to in countless online NDK tutorials; are they not installed any longer? And if not, is there a simple workaround to install them. I've Googled the problem to death with little joy.

Comment: Sorted! Thanks guys.
Although why the sample apps have been 'unbundled' and have to be located and downloaded separately as yet another wodge of files beats me.

Answer (score 3):

from NDK changelog:

> Android NDK, Revision 11 (March 2016)
>
> The samples are no longer included in the NDK package. They are instead available on [GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk).

Answer (score 1):

they samples appear to be now held on github. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk